# How to filter out redundant id rows with deviant values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

First post, so thank you in advance for any pointers! I have a dataframe with an issue similar to the following:

id  value 
10  25.03 
11  26.00 
11  0.95 
12  32.95 
13  34.43 
13  1.02

One can see that for id's 11 and 13 there are repeats with values that are clear outliers. How would I filter out these outlying values (in the actual dataframe, as here, the outliers are consistently smaller than the "correct" values)? Any tips? Sorry if this needs more clarity, ask and I will try to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas' [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method as such:

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=["id"], keep=...)`

and by adding proper values for the other argument, specially the `keep` argument, see the documentation for options.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want to retain the row with the maximum value for each ID, you can use the [groupby() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) followed by the [max() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html):

```
df.groupby(['id']).max()
```

This will firstly group all the rows with the same `id` together, then for each group, return the maximum `value`.